# Can I remove add-on cubes from my weapons after leaving the dialog?

Tags: cube-world

While playing Cube World, I stopped by the customization bench to upgrade my boomerang with my brand new fire spirit and 10 wood cubes. I left, and went to the Identifier to identifier some leftovers, only to find a better boomerang inside!

Therefore, is it possible to remove the cubes from the first boomerang to add them to the second? Fiddling around with them has proven unsuccessful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot move cubes to a different item, only take them off. They get destroyed when you remove customization cubes.